# Kronecker product, matrices

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, kronecker-product

Let $\mathbb{I}_{3}$ be the $3\times 3$ identity matrix, i. e.

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

and $e_1:=\begin{pmatrix}
1   \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}$,  $e_2:=\begin{pmatrix}
0   \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}$.

My question is, if the matrix $(\mathbb{I}_{3}\otimes e_1,\mathbb{I}_{3}\otimes e_2) $ is the same as $\mathbb{I}_{3}\otimes \mathbb{I}_{2}$? I have illustrated it, but do not know how to write this down mathematically.

$A\otimes B=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} B & a_{12} B \\ 
a_{21} B & a_{22} B 
\end{pmatrix}$

It is

$(\mathbb{I}_3 \otimes e_1,\mathbb{I}_3 \otimes e_2)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}$

But i don’t see in it $\mathbb{I}_{3}\otimes \mathbb{I}_{2}$.

Comment: The answer is yes. To make this rigorous you just have to say that the matrix $(A,B)$ is formed from the two matrices $A$ and $B$ by writing them as a single matrix or something like that. If you write out that example explicitly every reader will understand what you mean.

Comment: I added the first step. But how i see $\mathbb{I}_3\otimes\mathbb{I}_2$?

Comment: These are not even matrices. You need to go one step back and write out $\mathbb I_3\otimes e_1$ correctly. Here is the [usage guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Comment: @KurtG The two matrices have the same columns, but you don’t get the same matrix with the $(A,B)$ construction

Comment: Okey, then $\mathbb{I}_3\otimes e_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} $

Comment: @Fynn No, the matrices are not the same. They have the same columns, though

Comment: $$\mathbb{I}_3\otimes e_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ looks right. @Fynn, rest should be straightforward now, no? Please edit the question accordingly. I also realise that "the answer is yes" in my first comment seems wrong. So Ben  Grossmann has a point. It will become totally clear once you have written out all three matrices $\mathbb I_3\otimes e_1,\mathbb I_3\otimes e_2$ and last not least $\mathbb I_3\otimes I_3\,.$

Comment: @BenGrossmann I agree. Thanks!